# Adding multilevel entity to the database (CODE FIRST)

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to create a new record in my database, but the problem is a multilevel reference.

I have the following:

```
[Serializable]
public class CodeInfo
{
    public Guid CodeId { get; set; }
    public string Value get; set; }
}
```

and

```
[Serializable]
public class PersonInfo
{
    public Guid PersonId{ get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public CodeInfo Code get; set; }
}
```

I have the situation that I first update a person with a code like this:

```
var person = p.GetPerson(1234);
person.Name = "Jane";
Context.Person.Attach(person);
Context.Entry(person).State = EntityState.Modified;
Context.SaveChanges;
```

This works perfectly

When I do the following:

```
var person = new Person();
person.Name = "Jane";
person.Code = new Code();
person.Code = "existingCode";
Context.Person.Attach(person);
Context.Entry(person).State = EntityState.Added;
Context.SaveChanges;
```

This also works perfectly when I don't do an update before. When I execute both, I got an error:

> Attaching an entity of type 'Model.CodeInfo' failed because another
>   entity of the same type already has the same primary key value. This
>   can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an
>   entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have
>   conflicting key values. This may be because some entities are new and
>   have not yet received database-generated key values. In this case use
>   the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state to track the graph and
>   then set the state of non-new entities to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as
>   appropriate.

Also tried

```
 Context.Person.Add(person);
```

But this causes the same kind of error, entity framework is trying to create an CodeInfo into the database, but I only want to create a relationship into the object.

How to fix this?

...code simplified of course...

Comment: `person.Code = new Code();` `person.Code = "existingCode";` This is a problem.

Comment: added CodeId to the person class now, but I my honest opinion it's not very clean, but it solved the problem. Was hoping EF was a bit more intelligent.